# Reference a static string by index in an array?

Tags: php

I have a if statement evaluating 2 (numbers 1 and 0);

```
$output['mustHaveButtonText'] = ($dealer->mustHave == 0) ? 'Add to Must Have' : 'Remove From Must Have';
```

What I want is to assign the number to a string then display the sting instead of the number,

like

```
 0 =  "Must Have";  
 1 = "Must Not Have";
```

Comment: What does this have to do with zend framework?

Comment: Please change the title to something more appropriate, what does the Zend framework have to do with what you want to achieve?

Comment: I don't understand your question. What number? Where do you want to assign it? Do you not just need to replace the strings in the two arms of the conditional expression you quote?

Comment: Please try and write good titles in future.  For more information, please refer to the [faq#howtoask].  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, what you want to have is an array, like the following:

```
$text = array( 0 => 'Add to Must Have', 1 => 'Remove from Must Have');
```

then you can write:

```
$output['mustHaveButtonText'] = $text[$dealer->mustHave];
```

That way, even if you need the text multiple times, you need to define it only once, but can use it multiple times.

Comment: sorry guys , my bad, the above does work and thanks for the assitance, and what if I wanted to add a color based on what is displayed?, can that be done like a color for each element $text = array( 0 => 'Add to Must Have', 1 => 'Remove from Must Have');

Comment: Where do you want to now add a color? Sorry but this comment actually leaves me completely baffled on what you want... and if what you want here is output color, meaning you'd need CSS, then that's completely unrelated to the question above, please start a new one!